# How to access a specific accordion in a list of accordions generated inside ngfor in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a list of child accordions generated, each inside one panel of a list of panels generated using ngFor inside a parent accordion. I need to toggle a specific child accordion according to some logic. However it does not work, I cannot identify one accordion in the list of accordions generated in the ngfor.

In the html file

```
<ngb-accordion #acc1="ngbAccordion" >
 <ngb-panel #parentPanel *ngFor="let parentPanel of parentPanels; let parentPanelIndex=index" id="{{parentPanelIndex}}">
   <ngb-accordion #acc2="ngbAccordion" >
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let childPanel of ChildrenPanels; let childPanelIndex=index" id="{{childPanelIndex}}">
  ....
```

In the ts file:

```
@ViewChildren('parentPanels') parentPanels: QueryList<NgbPanel>;
....
this.parentPanels.toArray()[this.parentPanelIndex]
```

The last line would give me a reference to a specific panel according to the value stored in "parentPanelIndex". Now I have access to the parent panel, but I do not know how to get a reference to the accordion (acc2) in that panel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the querySelector to get the child at a custom position like

```
 const child = this.panelsView
    .nativeElement
    .querySelector(`:nth-child(${this.elem})`);
    this.result = child.innerHTML;
```

you can find an exemple here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwmajp

Comment: when do you want to get the id ? do you have an event or something ?

Comment: Yeah, but I cannot see multiple accordions generated in the example using ngfor. I do not understand how to apply it to my case. Can you please make it specific with ngfor of accordions

Comment: I am doing automatic save of the current open panel inside the current open accordion. So, I can identify the current panel through the id, but how can I identify its accordion.

Comment: A solution would be to make #acc2 a variable. So, accordion 1 would be #acc0, accordion two would be #acc1, etc... is this possible?

Comment: To do so you can take `#acc1` as a `@ViewChild` of your component get select `#acc2` through it or just declare both as `@ViewChild`

Comment: Yeah good point. I have edited the question and added (#operationPanel) to the ngbPanel. Using ViewChildren I can access all panels generated by the ngfor. But, I do not know how to access the accordion inside the panel when I just have an ElementRef to the panel. Any suggestions?

Comment: SOrry but i don't get you , what do you can't get #acc2 or ngb-panel under #acc2 ? can you please give me more details of the code and what you really want to do ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear....I want to toggle a specific panel under #acc2. As soon as I have a reference to the appropriate #acc2, it would be easy to toggle any panel in it (accordionreference.toggle(panelID)). The issue is that I have a few #acc2 (each in a different parent panel). Parent panels of #acc2 are generated inside a ngfor loop. I can get a reference to the appropriate parent panel for #acc2, but I do not know how to use that parent panel reference to access its child #acc2. Is this clear?

Comment: Can you get a nativeElement object with  the parent's reference ?

Comment: A very good question, at the time I wrote this question I was not able to, but now I can, I am updating the second part of the code in the question to reflect how I was able to access the parent panel

Answer (score 0):

`ngbAccordion` has a property known as `activeIds` which accepts *ID* of all the `ngb-panel` you want to keep open.

`activeIds` should be an array of *IDs* you want to keep open.

For more info here's the [official documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api).

Comment: Yeah great! I can identify the panels to be active using activeIDs. However, I am asking about identifying the accordion itself. You can id= to the panel to identify it, but how can you add a similar thing to the accordion to identify it.

Comment: Why would you like to identify the whole `accordion` ?

Comment: I want to close all its panels when needed by the logic, actually when specific buttons inside that specific accordion are pressed.

Comment: A solution would be to make #acc2 a variable. So, accordion 1 would be #acc0, accordion two would be #acc1, etc... is this possible?